# Is this a good pattern design for a Unity dispatcher for creating thread safe methods?

Tags: design-patterns, thread-safety, unity3d

Well, my intention here is to allow users to execute Unity methods/properties in other threads by using this Dispatcher implementation:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DepotToolkit.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A thread-safe class which holds a queue with actions to execute on the next Update() method. It can be used to make calls to the main thread for
    /// things such as UI Manipulation in Unity. It was developed for use in combination with the Firebase Unity plugin, which uses separate threads for event handling
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
    // : MonoSingleton<UnityDispatcher>
    {
        // TODO: Add timeout from https://gist.github.com/phizaz/f67f1ba7d25d30d8972c13b7b6a29319

        private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _executionQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
        public static ObservableCollection<Exception> Exceptions { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Exception>();

        // TODO
        //private static readonly Queue<Action<object>> _executionQueue1 = new Queue<Action<object>>();
        //private static readonly Queue<Action<object, object>> _executionQueue2 = new Queue<Action<object, object>>();

        private void Exceptions_OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                var item = newItem as Exception;
                Debug.LogError(item);
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            while (_executionQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if (_executionQueue.TryDequeue(out var act))
                    act.Invoke();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Locks the queue and adds the IEnumerator to the queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">IEnumerator function that will be executed from the main thread.</param>
        public void Enqueue(Action action)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(ActionWrapper(action));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue(EnumeratorJobWrapper job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue(JobWrapper job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue(JobWrapper<object> job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue<T>(JobWrapper<T> job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue<T1, TTResult>(JobWrapper<T1, TTResult> job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        public void Enqueue<T>(JobEnumeratorWrapper<T> job)
        {
            _executionQueue.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(JobWrapper(job));
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Locks the queue and adds the Action to the queue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">function that will be executed from the main thread.</param>
        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            Enqueue(action);
        }

        // Alias for Enqueue
        public void Invoke(EnumeratorJobWrapper job)
        {
            Enqueue(job);
        }

        public void Invoke(JobWrapper job)
        {
            Enqueue(job);
        }

        public void Invoke(JobWrapper<object> job)
        {
            Enqueue(job);
        }

        public void Invoke<T>(JobWrapper<T> job)
        {
            Enqueue(job);
        }

        public void Invoke<T1, TResult>(JobWrapper<T1, TResult> job)
        {
            Enqueue(job);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Locks the queue and adds the Action to the queue, returning a Task which is completed when the action completes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">function that will be executed from the main thread.</param>
        /// <returns>A Task that can be awaited until the action completes</returns>
        public Task EnqueueAsync(Action action)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            void WrappedAction()
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tcs.TrySetException(ex);
                }
            }

            Enqueue(WrappedAction);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        private IEnumerator ActionWrapper(Action a)
        {
            a();
            yield return null;
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper(EnumeratorJobWrapper wrap)
        {
            var enumerator = wrap.Callback;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                object obj = null;
                bool isException = false;
                try
                {
                    obj = enumerator.Current;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.LogException(ex);
                    isException = true;
                }

                if (!isException)
                    yield return obj;
                else
                    yield break;
            }

            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper(JobWrapper wrap)
        {
            try
            {
                wrap.Callback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogException(ex);
                //Exceptions.Add(ex);
            }

            yield return null;
            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper(JobWrapper<object> wrap)
        {
            object result = null;
            try
            {
                wrap.Job.Invoke(out result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogException(ex);
                //Exceptions.Add(ex);
            }

            wrap.Result = result;
            yield return null;
            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper<T>(JobWrapper<T> wrap)
        {
            T result = default;
            try
            {
                wrap.Job.Invoke(out result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogException(ex);
                //Exceptions.Add(ex);
            }

            wrap.Result = result;
            yield return null;
            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper<T1, TResult>(JobWrapper<T1, TResult> wrap)
        {
            TResult result = default;
            try
            {
                wrap.Job.Invoke(wrap.Value, out result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogException(ex);
                //Exceptions.Add(ex);
            }

            wrap.Result = result;
            yield return null;
            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private IEnumerator JobWrapper<T>(JobEnumeratorWrapper<T> wrap)
        {
            var enumerator = wrap.Job.Invoke(out var result);
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) yield return null;
            wrap.Result = result;
            wrap.Finished.Set();
        }

        private static UnityDispatcher _instance;

        public static UnityDispatcher Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Search for existing instance.
                        _instance = (UnityDispatcher)FindObjectOfType(typeof(UnityDispatcher));

                        // Create new instance if one doesn't already exist.
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            // Need to create a new GameObject to attach the singleton to.
                            var singletonObject = new GameObject();
                            _instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<UnityDispatcher>();
                            singletonObject.name = $"{nameof(UnityDispatcher)} (Singleton)";

                            //((MonoSingleton<T>)_instance).IsStarted = false;

                            // Make instance persistent.

                            if (Application.isPlaying) DontDestroyOnLoad(singletonObject);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // This is not thread safe
                        throw new Exception(
                            "UnityMainThreadDispatcher could not find the UnityMainThreadDispatcher object. Please ensure you have added the MainThreadExecutor Prefab to your scene.");
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private void Awake()
        {
            Exceptions.CollectionChanged += Exceptions_OnCollectionChanged;

            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = this;
                DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            }
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            _instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `JobWrapper` class is this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

namespace DepotToolkit.Utils
{
    public class EnumeratorJobWrapper
    {
        public IEnumerator Callback { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Finished { get; }

        private EnumeratorJobWrapper()
        {
        }

        public EnumeratorJobWrapper(IEnumerator callback, ManualResetEvent finished)
        {
            Callback = callback;
            Finished = finished;
        }
    }

    public class JobWrapper
    {
        public Action Callback { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Finished { get; }

        private JobWrapper()
        {
        }

        public JobWrapper(Action callback, ManualResetEvent finished)
        {
            Callback = callback;
            Finished = finished;
        }
    }

    public class JobWrapper<T>
    {
        public delegate void DelegateJob(out T result);

        public DelegateJob Job { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Finished { get; }
        public T Result { get; set; }

        private JobWrapper()
        {
        }

        public JobWrapper(DelegateJob job, ManualResetEvent finished)
        {
            Job = job;
            Finished = finished;
        }
    }

    public class JobWrapper<T1, TResult>
    {
        public delegate void DelegateJob(T1 t1, out TResult result);

        public DelegateJob Job { get; }
        public ManualResetEvent Finished { get; }
        public T1 Value { get; }
        public TResult Result { get; set; }

        private JobWrapper()
        {
        }

        public JobWrapper(T1 value, DelegateJob job, ManualResetEvent finished)
        {
            Value = value;
            Job = job;
            Finished = finished;
        }
    }
}
```

An example of what I'm doing:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using DepotToolkit.Utils;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Core;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;

namespace DepotToolkit.CommonCode
{
    public static class ThreadSafeUtils
    {
        internal class ThreadChecker : MonoSingleton<ThreadChecker>
        {
            public Thread UnityThread { get; private set; }

            private void Awake()
            {
                UnityThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsMainThread => Thread.CurrentThread.Equals(ThreadChecker.Instance.UnityThread);

        public static T[] ThreadSafe_GetComponentsInChildren<T>(this GameObject obj)
        {
            if (IsMainThread)
                return obj.GetComponentsInChildren<T>();

            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<GameObject, T[]>(obj, Impl_GetComponentsInChildren, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
        }

        private static void Impl_GetComponentsInChildren<T>(GameObject obj, out T[] result)
        {
            result = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
        }

        // Object.Instantiate

        public static GameObject Instantiate(GameObject obj)
        {
            if (IsMainThread)
                return Object.Instantiate(obj);

            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<GameObject, GameObject>(obj, Impl_Instantiate, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
        }

        private static void Impl_Instantiate(GameObject obj, out GameObject result)
        {
            result = Object.Instantiate(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm checking If I'm in the current thread by creating a MonoSingleton instance of a `MonoBehaviour`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using DepotToolkit.Utils;
using uzLib.Lite.ExternalCode.Extensions;
using uzSourceToolkit.ThirdParty.uSrcTools.Extensions;

namespace UnityEngine.Core
{
#if UNITY_2020 || UNITY_2019 || UNITY_2018 || UNITY_2017 || UNITY_5

    /// <summary>
    ///     Inherit from this base class to create a singleton.
    ///     e.g. public class MyClassName : Singleton<MyClassName> {}
    /// </summary>
    public class MonoSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour // , IStarted
        where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Check to see if we're about to be destroyed.
        private static bool m_ShuttingDown;

        private static readonly object m_Lock = new object();
        protected static T m_Instance;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Access singleton instance through this propriety.
        /// </summary>
        public static T Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_ShuttingDown)
                {
                    // FIX: Shutting down takes affect after playing a scene, this makes (ie) SteamWorkshopWrapper unavailable on Editor
                    // (check for ExecuteInEditrMode attribute, if available, shutthing down shuld not be performed)
                    // ReSharper disable once ConditionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse
                    //                    if (MonoSingletonSettings.ShowWarning)
                    //#pragma warning disable 162
                    //                        // ReSharper disable once HeuristicUnreachableCode
                    //                        Debug.LogWarning("[Singleton] Instance '" + typeof(T) +
                    //                                     "' already destroyed. Returning null.");
                    //#pragma warning restore 162
                    return null;
                }

                lock (m_Lock)
                {
                    if (m_Instance == null)
                    {
                        // Search for existing instance.
                        try
                        {
                            m_Instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));
                        }
                        catch (UnityException)
                        {
                            // Call with the Dispatcher...

                            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                            var job = new JobWrapper<T>(Impl_GetInstance, mre);
                            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
                            mre.WaitOne();
                            m_Instance = job.Result;
                        }

                        // Create new instance if one doesn't already exist.
                        if (m_Instance == null)
                        {
                            // Need to create a new GameObject to attach the singleton to.
                            try
                            {
                                var singletonObject = new GameObject();
                                m_Instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<T>();
                                singletonObject.name = typeof(T).Name + " (Singleton)";

                                //((MonoSingleton<T>)m_Instance).IsStarted = false;

                                // Make instance persistent.
                                if (IsPlaying()) DoAction(() => DontDestroyOnLoad(singletonObject)); // TODO
                            }
                            catch (UnityException)
                            {
                                var singletonObject = CreateGameObject();
                                m_Instance = AddComponent<T>(singletonObject);
                                DoAction(() => singletonObject.name = typeof(T).Name + " (Singleton)");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return m_Instance;
                }
            }
            protected set => m_Instance = value;
        }

        private static void Impl_GetInstance(out T result)
        {
            result = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));
        }

        private static void Impl_CreateInstance(out GameObject obj)
        {
            obj = new GameObject();
        }

        private static void Impl_IsPlaying(out bool result)
        {
            result = Application.isPlaying;
        }

        private static void Impl_AddComponent<TMethod>(GameObject obj, out TMethod result)
            where TMethod : Component
        {
            result = obj.AddComponent<TMethod>();
        }

        private static GameObject CreateGameObject()
        {
            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<GameObject>(Impl_CreateInstance, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
        }

        private static TMethod AddComponent<TMethod>(GameObject gameObject)
            where TMethod : Component
        {
            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<GameObject, TMethod>(gameObject, Impl_AddComponent, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
        }

        private static void DoAction(Action action)
        {
            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper(action, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
        }

        private static bool IsPlaying()
        {
            var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<bool>(Impl_IsPlaying, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
        }

        public bool ExecuteInEditMode => GetType().IsExecutingInEditMode();

        public bool IsStarted { get; set; }

        public static T Create()
        {
            var go = new GameObject(typeof(T).Name);
            return go.GetOrAddComponent<T>();
        }

        private void OnApplicationQuit()
        {
            if (!ExecuteInEditMode) m_ShuttingDown = true;
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (!ExecuteInEditMode) m_ShuttingDown = true;
        }
    }

#endif
}
```

As you can see, the `MonoSingleton` class is already protected from external thread calls by using *try/catch* blocks with `UnityExceptions`.

My main three concerns about my implementation are the following:

- I'm not able to figure out how to make easier the implementation of the `JobWrapper`, as you can see every time I need to create a thread-safe method I use the following four lines that are repeated lots and lots of times:

```cs
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var job = new JobWrapper<GameObject, T[]>(obj, Impl_GetComponentsInChildren, mre);
            UnityDispatcher.Instance.Invoke(job);
            mre.WaitOne();
            return job.Result;
```

- On the attached code from above you can see `Impl_GetComponentsInChildren` which is the alias for doing this simple thing (**THAT IS EXECUTED ON THE UNITY THREAD**):

```cs
private static void Impl_GetComponentsInChildren<T>(GameObject obj, out T[] result)
        {
            result = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
        }
```

My question here is there a nicer way to do this?

- Has my Unity Dispatcher a good design on the memory / CPU usage part? I mean, this will be called lots and lots of times and I didn't benchmark this yet. So, can you suggest to me something lighter or a tip to keep in mind for this topic?
- Other problems could be the loss of the stack trace. Can somebody give a tip for this?

Comment: How did you get on with this, and what are you polling at a higher rate? Am trying to solve the problem of detecting input at far faster rates than update/fixedUpdate, and thinking to use threads... too....